# redirect to 404 page if there is get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

In my website when I add any parameters, it is redirecting to 404 page.

For example, in http://www.surplusfurniture.com/en/sydney/mattresses/mattresses/1/?xyz is redirecting to 404 page.

but http://www.surplusfurniture.com/en/sydney/mattresses/mattresses/1/ is working.

Please suggest because there is no issue in htaccess.

Comment: After `/` question mark is given. It should be after 1?xyz

Comment: tried with this method (http://www.surplusfurniture.com/en/sydney/mattresses/mattresses/1?xyz ) but not working

Comment: Before that just tell what are going to achieve by giving ?xyz

Comment: I just  want to reload the page with the parameter. its working for the url http://www.surplusfurniture.com/?xyz.

Comment: Yes but you should accept that parametr with key value in  your controller

Comment: What rewrite rules do you have in your .htaccess file

Comment: Actually i 'm new to php. i found the following rewrite rules in htaccess

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} YOURSTRING=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.surplusfurniture\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.surplusfurniture.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^surplusfurniture.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.surplusfurniture.com$1 [R=301,L]